# $C^{k, \alpha}$ gradients $\implies C^{k + 1, \alpha}$ level sets

Tags: smoothness

Referring to the statement **in the parentheses below** (*Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE, Xavier Ros-Oton, p. 172*)

[image]

-- the authors go forward to make a bootstrapping argument that uses this result:

> For arbitrary $k$, it holds that $\nu^i \in C^{k, \alpha} \implies C^{k + 1, \alpha}$ regularity of the level sets.

here $\alpha$ is just the Hoelder exponent of the function, and $\nu$ is the normal to the level set.
Does anyone know of a proof of this result?

Comment: The sought result is stated in 2 places -- the title and the reference to the parentheses from the first paragraph. What would help to clarify this more? @PiotrHajlasz

Comment: I removed my close vote and my comment (sorry for a hasty reaction), I will write the proof instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show a special case of your problem. You can then adapt the argument
to your situation.

> *$f:B^n(0,2)\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz.  I will show that if the normal vector to the graph of $f$ is Lipschitz continuous as a function on the graph then, $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $B^n(0,1)$ i.e., $f\in C^{1,1}$.*

The inner unit normal vector in terms of $\nabla f$ is given by
$$
\nu(p(x'))=\frac{(-\nabla f(x'),1)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f(x')|^2}},
\qquad
\text{so}
\qquad
\pi(\nu(p(x'))=\frac{-\nabla f(x')}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f(x')|^2}},
$$
where $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, $\pi(x',x_n)=x'$ is the orthogonal projection.
Since $\Psi(\Phi(z))=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, where
$\Psi(z)=-z/\sqrt{1-|z|^2}$ and $\Phi(z)=-z/\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$, it follows that
$$
\nabla f(x')=\Psi\left(\frac{-\nabla f(x')}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f(x')|^2}}\right)=\Psi(\pi(\nu(x',f(x'))))
\quad
\text{for $x'\in B^n(0,1)$.}
$$
This proves Lipschitz continuity of $\nabla f$ in $B^n(0,1)$, as a composition of Lipschitz functions.
The only issue could be the Lipschitz continuity of $\Psi$: it is a smooth function defined for $|z|<1$, but it is unbounded. However, this does not cause any problems here, because $|\nabla f|$ is bounded, say $|\nabla f|\leq M$ on $B^n(0,1)$ and hence
$$
\left|\frac{-\nabla f(x')}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f(x')|^2}}\right|\leq \frac{M}{\sqrt{1+M^2}}<1.
$$